# Unhide Test Explorer in Visual Studio when running MsTest

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

In VS2012 my Test Explorer window is set to Auto Hide

[image]
How to make this window appear when I run tests eg:

Ctrl+R, T

I am keen to just use the VS test runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto focus/unhide functionality is not enabled for the Test Explorer